# How to go one step above in a folder path by using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory in c#

Tags: c#

I am using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` and I want to go one step backwards but couldn't figure out how? Below is the example,

CODE :

`string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;`

RESULT :

`"C:\\Mainline Code\\IxExpress\\.NET Applications\\IXTextIndexBuilder\\IXTextIndexBuilder\\bin\\Debug\\"`

EXPECTED RESULT:

`"C:\\Mainline Code\\IxExpress\\.NET Applications\\IXTextIndexBuilder\\IXTextIndexBuilder\\bin"`

Comment: What happens if you are already in `C:`?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Can you please elaborate?

Comment: What happens if `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` is `"C:\\"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something like the following to get the parent of a given directory:

```
        string dirName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; // Starting Dir
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(dirName);
        DirectoryInfo parentDir = fileInfo.Directory.Parent;
        string parentDirName = parentDir.FullName; // Parent of Starting Dir
```

Comment: Thank you. I was just about to post the similar answer that I just found out.

My Code : 

`String licenseKeyPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
DirectoryInfo baseDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(licenseKeyPath);
String oneStepBackwardInPath = baseDirInfo.Parent.FullName;`  

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Use following snippet:

```
string path = (new FileInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)).Directory.Parent.FullName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Directory.GetParent(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).Parent.FullName