# c# built-in function to get path of bin folder and not the application folder such as bin\Debug or bin\Release

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

We can get path of an application directory as follows. But this gives us the `...\bin\Debug` or `...\bin\Release` based on debug of release mode of the app. Question: How can we get the path of `bin` folder **WITHOUT** doing string manipulation - i.e. is there a built-in function for it?

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Comment: The "bin" folder is only relevant in the context of VS Studio and more specifically as the output path for MS Build the VS runs on your behalf.  Look at the "Build" tab of the project properties; you can change the relative path to anything you want; i.e. it does not need to be named "bin".  What are you trying to achieve by getting this path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no function like that because it is not necessary that the *bin* folder be always there.

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` returns the current directory from where your code is executing. This is by default `...\bin\Debug` (or `...\bin\Release`) when you are running from Visual Studio, but that would not be the case always.

If your aim is to go one level up from current base directory without string manipulation, you can try something like this (as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30719075/6835535))

```
string dirName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; // Starting Dir
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(dirName);
DirectoryInfo parentDir = fileInfo.Directory.Parent;
string parentDirName = parentDir.FullName; // Parent of Starting Dir
```